# Codeigniter Datatables Multiple Row Select for Same Item in Different Prices

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, datatable

I have a codeigniter project that used to manage purchases & issues of items. Tables are as follows :

## store_item

```
+---------+-----------+
| item_id | item_name |
+---------+-----------+
|       1 | Pen       |
|       2 | A4        |
|       3 | Ruler     |
|       4 | Stapler   |
|       5 | A3        |
+---------+-----------+
```

## store_update_stock

```
+-----------------+------------+---------------+-------------+
| update_stock_id | invoice_no | prchased_date | order_state |
+-----------------+------------+---------------+-------------+
|               1 | A0001      | 2019-10-05    | purchase    |
|               2 | A0002      | 2019-10-06    | purchase    |
|               3 | B0003      | 2019-10-07    | issue       |
+-----------------+------------+---------------+-------------+
```

## store_update_stock_details

```
+-------------------------+-----------------+------+-----+------------+
| update_stock_details_id | update_stock_id | item | qty | unit_price |
+-------------------------+-----------------+------+-----+------------+
|                       1 |               1 |    1 |  50 |      10.00 |
|                       2 |               1 |    4 |  10 |     250.00 |
|                       3 |               2 |    1 | 100 |      10.50 |
|                       4 |               3 |    1 |   2 |      10.00 |
|                       5 |               3 |    4 |   1 |     250.00 |
|                       6 |               3 |    1 |   4 |      10.50 |
+-------------------------+-----------------+------+-----+------------+
```

Then I need to find the balances of items after performing issues. In this example the desired output as follows and the output should be viewed in my view to perform issues again. (In other words even the same item should be viewed separately in different prices.

```
+-----------+-----+------------+
| item_name | qty | unit_price |
+-----------+-----+------------+
| Pen       |  48 |      10.00 |
| Pen       |  96 |      10.50 |
+-----------+-----+------------+
```

[image: View]

## Controller

```
public function isExistProduct()
    {    
        $id = $this->input->get('q');
        $data = $this->Item_model->isExistProduct($id);
        if (!empty($data)) {
            echo json_encode(array('status' => true, 'data' => $data));
        } else {
            echo json_encode(array('status' => false));
        }
    }
```

## Model (Used this Query)

```
    public function isExistProduct($q)
        {
            if (!empty($q)) {           

                $this->db->select("store_item.item_id, store_item.item_name, sum(qty) as qty, unit_price as up");
                $this->db->from('store_update_stock_details');
                $this->db->join('store_update_stock', 'store_update_stock_details.update_stock_id=store_update_stock.update_stock_id');
                $this->db->join('store_item', 'store_update_stock_details.item=store_item.item_id');            
                $this->db->where("store_update_stock.status=1 and store_item.item_id= $q");           
                $this->db->group_by( 'store_item.item_id','store_update_stock_details.unit_price');       
                $q1 = $this->db->get();
                if ($q1->num_rows() > 0) {
                    return $q1->result_array();
                }
                return 0;
            }
        }
Relevant parts of View
======================
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).on("change", "#item", function () {

        $.ajax({
            'url': '<?=site_url("item/isExistProduct/?q=")?>' + $('#item').val(),
            'method': 'GET',
            'success': function (data) {


                var jData = JSON.parse(data);
                if (jData.status == true) {

                jData.data.forEach(data => {
                    $('#request_table').append('<tr>' +
                        '<td ><span id="product" >' + jData.data[0].item_name + '</span>' +
                        '<input type="hidden" id="item_id[]" name="item_id[]" value="' + jData.data[0].item_id + '">' +
                        '</td>' +                       
                        '<td class="text-center">' + jData.data[0].qty + '</td>' +                      
                        '<td class="text-center"><input class="form-control text-right"  disabled id="sales_price[]" name="sales_price[]" value="' + jData.data[0].up+ '"></td>' +
                        '<td class="text-center"><input class="form-control text-center rquantity" data-qty-bal="' + jData.data[0].qty + '" autofocus required type="number" step="any" id="qty[]" name="qty[]" ></td>' +   
                        '<td class="text-center" ><i class="fa fa-remove remove" style="cursor: pointer"></i></td>' +
                        '</tr>');
                    })
                }

            },
            'error': function () {

            }
        });


    });
</script>

<div class="col-md-12 column">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="control-group table-group">
                            <label class="table-label">Issue Items *</label>

                            <div class="controls table-controls">
                                <table id="request_table"
                                       class="table items table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
                                    <thead>
                                    <tr class="" style="background-color: #ff66a3 !important;">
                                        <th class="col-md-5">Item Name</th>
                                        <th class="text-center col-md-2">Available Qty</th>                                        
                                        <th class="text-center col-md-2">Unit Price</th>
                                        <th class="text-center col-md-2">Issuing Qty</th>

                                        </th>
                                        <th class="col-md-2" style="width: 30px !important; text-align: center;">
                                            <i class="fa fa-trash-o" style="opacity:0.5; filter:alpha(opacity=50);"></i>
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody></tbody>
                                    <tfoot>
                                    <tr id="tfoot" class="tfoot active">
                                        <th colspan="2">Total</th>
                                        <th class="text-right"></th>
                                        <th class="text-center">0</th>

                                        <th class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"
                                                                   style="opacity:0.5; filter:alpha(opacity=50);"></i>
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                    </tfoot>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <button type="submit" id="add_sale" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Issue</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

All parts are working fine. But the view outs only the following output as per model
[image: View1]

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

When you are using multiple values in your `group_by` function, you need to specify it as an array. For example, you can add this to your code replace this

```
$this->db->group_by( 'store_item.item_id','store_update_stock_details.unit_price');
```

with

```
$this->db->group_by(array( 'store_item.item_id','store_update_stock_details.unit_price'));
```

Comment: @ seuncrowther. But see again my above images (Outputs). I need to get the output as my first image

Comment: Can I get a link to troubleshoot?